# Width issues with divs

Tags: html, css

I don't understand why the width of these two divs are different. My goal is to have margins at each side of the page. Furthermore i don't understand why there is more space at the left side than the right side when they should be equal.

http://jsfiddle.net/dazakip/u7d59901/2/

```
body {
  margin-left: 9%;
  margin-right: 9%;

}

.nav {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  padding-top: 3px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: green;
}

.logo {
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #C7D0D5;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Not sure you've shared the right fiddle there

Comment: @cameronjonesweb it should be there now! forgot to save it before closing yikes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add padding, it adds it to the size, so your width of .logo is 100% + 40px. To fix this set the box sizing to border-box.

```
.logo {
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #C7D0D5;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you are missing `box-sizing: border-box;` on your div, paddings are increasing overall width there

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the box-sizing property which changes the behaviour of margins to a more intuitive way: http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

Answer (score 1):

It's because you set the padding of .logo by 20px. So you will get more 20px width in the left and right of your .logo.

Try to remove it or add "box-sizing: border-box;" so your .logo width will not expand even if you give padding.